# Private Key in HD Account Bither Watch Only

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, watch-only, bither

I have a watch only HD account in Bither and I've got a password of the wallet but I don't have a private Key. I need to send  BTC received in that account to another address in another account

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have the private key, you cannot spend the bitcoin in a watch-only wallet. There is no way to find, calculate, or recover a private key for a given address.

After all, if you were able to do that, Bitcoin, and many other systems that use public key cryptography, would be broken.

Beware: some scams involve a scammer telling you to pay for access to a private key for an address that was set up as a watch-only address. If this sounds like the situation you are in, so not send the scammer any money, you will likely receive nothing in return.

Comment: How can I draw my BTC from that account? Is there any way to prove my identity? Passport or any other identity card?

Comment: You cannot. BTC transaction’s require no identification, and there is no central admin to orchestrate such a thing in any case. Where did you get the watch only address from in the first place?

Comment: I created it in Bither. It is an HD account and i gave the address but now i don't have any private key

Comment: *"I gave the address"* -> yes, where did you get that address in the first place?

Comment: I created it in Bither

Comment: So Bither has the private key, presumably?

Comment: @RuiFazendeiro Are you trying to use Bither in its offline mode? It should be quite intuitive. Did you have another offline device with Bither (cold) installed, which generated your wallet in the beginning?

Comment: @PieterWuille It's not straightforward to import xpub into Bither. It seemed to be designed to be used in pairs, one is online but watch-only (hot), and the other is offline (cold).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in two parts and you must have two separate devices (two phones / or a Phone & computer) in front of you:

Part 1:

1. Open your orignal Bither app and make sure to highlight (dark blue) the HD Account section on the Upper Left side of the app.
2. Then select the H [HD Account] Icon
3. A Query box will open with two choices:
   a..HD Account Seed QR Code
   b..HD Account Seed Phrase
4. Select option (a.) HD Account Seed QR Code
5. The QR Code will appear and keep it visible on the screen.

Part 2: (Switch to the device with the new Bither App)

1. If not already accomplished, download a new Bither app on an Iphone or Android.
2. IMPORTANT: When setting up this new Bither account on that device DO NOT select the + (plus or add) option.
3. Instead, go to Settings icon and select Advanced Options
4. Then select Import Private Key
5. Then select from Bither Private Key QR Code
6. At this point the device's camera should activate (turn on automatically)
7. Using the second device's camera, scan the QR code from the other device (from part 1 / step #5 above).
8. Your HD Account will be imported into the your new Bither application and you will now be able to access your $$$.

Let me know if you succeed?

Basically, your first Bither application was outdated and it was unable to provide a current Private Key format, nor did it show any funds available in the original HD Account. At least mine didn't before I completed the above steps.

Best regards,
Scott

Comment: Bither supports offline signing, doesn't it? The private keys/mnemonic words/HD seed doesn't need to be transferred out, unless the offline signing functionality is broken.